# custom validation message in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

how to give custom laravel message in my coding i am new in laravel

```
$validatedData = $r->validate([
            'preference' => 'required',
            'objective_1' => 'required',
            'objective_2' => 'required',
            'objective_5' => 'required',
        ]);
        if (empty($r->session()->get('sessForm'))) {
            $r->session()->put('sessForm', $validatedData);
        } else {
            $sessForm = $r->session()->get('sessForm');
            $r->session()->put('sessForm', $sessForm);
        }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom validator. Check the [documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) You can get messages from **$errors** variable in blade template.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
], [
    'title.required' => 'Title required custom message',
    'title.unique' => 'Title unique custom message',
    // ...
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
}
```

If you want to send redirect with data. You can use

```
redirect()->route('route')->with('data', 'test');
```

You can get after redirect

```
session('data')
```